# Error when trying installing osmread module on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, installation

I am trying to install `osmread` on windows via Ubuntu, but I am getting an EnvironmentError.

I am using Ubuntu to run the code through a virtual env. once I prompt it to install osmread.

The command line I am using is `pip install osmread`

The python version I have is 2.7 and the python code I want to run is also using version 2.7

Once I run the command line, an error pops up:
 `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/c/Users/azza.abdallah/Documents/CODE/myenv/lin/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/ElementInclude.py'`

Comment: What do you mean by `on windows via Ubuntu`?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf, I meant on an Ubuntu VS command prompt. I'm using it because the code I have to run can only be run on a Linux and I have a Windows PC

Comment: Did you try using `sudo pip install osmread`.